# pass an array from JQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I want to pass an array from Jquery to PHP.

My jquery:

```
var jsonFormat = JSON.stringify(myArray);

$.post("myPHPFile.php", jsonFormat).done(function(data) {
    $('.foo').append(data);
});
```

I see myArray in the browser console as expected

My PHP:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
//echo json_decode(array('success' => 'yes'));


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

    $jsonFormat = $_POST['jsonFormat']; 

    echo $jsonFormat;

}
?>
```

In the browser console I get status 200 ok, but no response. I am expecting to see the array as a response.

Comment: try to `print_r($_POST)` and see the parameters that posted, actually there might be no parameter by this `jsonFormat` as you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed PHP a request with a JSON body, but you are trying to treat it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, not `application/json` data.

Use `$.post("myPHPFile.php", { myData: myArray })` and `$_POST['myData']` instead. jQuery will encode the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then (it will even default to using PHP's unusual naming conventions).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar to this:

Jquery

```
$.post("myPHPFile.php", myArray.serialize(), function(data) {
    $(".foo").append(data);
}, "json");
```

myArray.serialize() turns your array into a string that will be posted to your PHP file like this: `var1=text&var2=text`

PHP

```
<?php
    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
    // repeat for each variable being posted.

    // your php code that does whatever it will do with the variables.

    // data to return to Jquery will be put back into an array like this:
    $return['var3'] = $var3;
    $return['var4'] = $var4;

    echo json_encode($return);
    unset($_POST);
?>
```

The data returned is datatype = json which can be accessed in your Jquery code like this: `data.var3   data.var4`

Comment: I am getting serialize is not a function

Comment: Well it is a function, so maybe you were using it wrong. Certainly doesn't require a downvote, because the code does work. I use it to submit form variables in my jquery scripts. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/